# Skooma input validator

Tags: validation, functional-programming, elixir, phoenix-framework

I was given a task to implement an input validator with the Skooma library https://github.com/bobfp/skooma#validators

The general concept is pretty clear, but for some inputs I have a list of "legal" words, and I have zero clue on how to implement the validation for this case.
Hence why I came here, I wanted to ask if you know any examples / projects that used this library? I googled but didn't find anything.
Of if you have any other tipps just let me know! 
This is the example:

my schema:

```
schema = %{
:titel => :string, 
:category => :string, 
:high_level_category => :string, 
:description => :string, 
:potential_impacts => :string, 
:affected_assets => :string, 
:rating => :string }
```

The legal inputs for category:

```
category = %{core: 'Core network threats', access: 'Access network threats', multi: 'Multi edge computing threats',
virtualisation: 'Virtualisation threats', phyiscal: 'Physical infrastructure threats', generic: 'Generic threats'}
```

I tried it with a normal list as well, such as

```
category = ['Core network threats', 'Access network threats', 'Multi edge computing threats' .......]
```

But I just cant get my head around how to check if the :category is present in the category list.

Comment: Single quotation mark (`'`) is different from double (`"`) in Elixir. I think what you meant here was the *double quotation mark*, wasn't it?

Comment: @qhwa yeah you are right! I used php a lot in the past few months so I am used to the single quotation mark. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [custom validator](https://github.com/bobfp/skooma#custom-validators) function, here's an example:

```
alias Skooma.Validators

@valid_categories [
  "Access network threats",
  "Core network threats",
  "Generic threats",
  "Multi edge computing threats",
  "Physical infrastructure threats",
  "Virtualisation threats"
]

def valid?(data), do: Skooma.valid?(data, schema())

defp schema,
  do: %{
    :category => [:string, inclusion(@valid_categories)],
    ... # rest of the schema
  }

# copied from:
# https://github.com/bobfp/skooma/blob/master/lib/validators.ex#L38-L48
defp inclusion(values_list) when is_list(values_list) do
  fn data ->
    bool = data in values_list

    if bool do
      :ok
    else
      {:error, "Value is not included in the options: #{inspect(values_list)}"}
    end
  end
end
```

You can replace the `inclusion` function with [`Validators.inclusion/1`](https://github.com/bobfp/skooma/blob/master/lib/validators.ex#L38-L48). In this case, you'll need to install Skooma from Github because it has not been published as speaking today (31 Jan 2022).